# Making particle bounce off a line with friction

Tags: c#, physics

So I'm making a game and I need a particle to bounce off a line. I've got this so far:

```
public static Vector2f Reflect(this Vector2f vec, Vector2f axis) //vec is velocity
    {
        Vector2f result = vec - 2f * axis * axis.Dot(vec);
        return result;
    }
```

Which works fine, but then I decided I wanted to be able to change the bounciness and friction of the bounce. I got bounciness down...

```
public static Vector2f Reflect(this Vector2f vec, Vector2f axis, float bounciness) //Bounciness goes from 0 to 1, 0 being not bouncy and 1 being perfectly bouncy
    {
        var reflect = (1 + bounciness); //2f

        Vector2f result = vec - reflect * axis * axis.Dot(vec);
        return result;
    }
```

But when I tried to add friction, everything went to hell and back...

```
public static Vector2f Reflect(this Vector2f vec, Vector2f axis, float bounciness, float friction) //Does not work at all!
    {
        var reflect = (1 + bounciness); //2f

        Vector2f subtract = reflect * axis * axis.Dot(vec);
        Vector2f subtract2 = axis * axis.Dot(vec);
        Vector2f result = vec - subtract;
        result -= axis.PerpendicularLeft() * subtract2.Length() * friction;
        return result;
    }
```

Any physics guys willing to help me out with this?

(if you're not sure what I mean with the friction of a bounce see this: http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/diagrams/A-1_particle_collision.swf)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a matter of multiplying the component velocity parallel to the surface by the desired friction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the physics answer. (I'm not sure exactly what `bounciness` and all refer to, but this should be easy to calculate)

Let's take a particle moving towards the wall with u<sub>y</sub>, and parallel to it with u<sub>x</sub>. It's coefficient of restitution is e (akin to 'bounciness', for perfectly bouncy it's 1. For normal items it's less than 1). Also, let the friction coefficient be m (The correct mathematical symbol for this is *mu*, represented as μ.  But since that's visually similar to the 'u' value we're already using, we'll instead use 'm' for clarity). A friction coefficient is usually greater than 1.

Now, the resultant velocities will be:

- v<sub>y</sub> = -eu<sub>y</sub>
- v<sub>x</sub> = u<sub>x</sub> + m(e-1)u<sub>y</sub>

Comment: there's something wrong here: after your edits, the friction coefficient no longer is taken into account...

Comment: @Mac: Oh whoops, I forgot that I'd used "m" for friction coefficient. To me, It looked like a dimensional error, since m usually refers to mass--I though I'd neglected to cancel it out. I had come to this question to quickly copy the formulae for use [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22945/what-are-all-the-equations-we-use-to-calculate-how-bounces-work), and the physicist in me evidently didn't like the dimensional error.